# Open app by URL and close other Activity

Tags: android, url, android-activity

I have two type of activity :

1. Login
2. Content

I am using URL to change user or to login, so If I am on Content Activity and after it I am trying to open app by URL then Login Activity open(as needed) BUT after I press back Content Activity shows. 
So What I need to do to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and it solved my problem.